# Difference between String.valueOf() and new String()

Tags: java, string

What is the difference between  String.valueOf() and new String()? When would you use one over the other?

example 1:

```
public String fun(){

 int foo = 55;
 return String.valueOf(foo);

}
```

example 2:

```
public String fun(){

int foo = 55;
return new String(foo);

}
```

Update: Yes, the second example doesn't compile as pointed out by others below. I didn't realize it because I have been using new String("something" + foo) and it has worked, as pointed out by fastcodejava. So is there a difference between the two if I use new String("something" + foo) or String.valueOf(foo) ?

Comment: The second example doesn't compile.

Comment: An alternative is `Integer.toString(foo)`

Comment: Who cares? They do the same thing and both create a String object to be returned.

Comment: really? 3 downvotes for this question? I explained my source of confusion by updating the question. whatever. at least i'm clear about this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code won't even compile. But if you did `return new String("" + foo);`, it would. They are pretty much same after that.

Comment: I see. I have been using new String("something" + foo) and it works, so your answer greatly clarified things. Thank you!

Comment: this is a pretty bad Java advice - it creates 2 unnecessary objects

Comment: There is no point to do new String("" +foo); ""+foo itself is already a new String.

Answer (score 2):

The first method takes an integer and converts it to String. 
However, the second method is just a constructor that creates a new object of type String. It cannot take an integer as argument.

Answer (score 2):

There is no constructor for [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) that takes a single integer.

- `String(byte[] bytes)`
- `String(char[] value)`
- `String(String original)`
- `String(StringBuffer buffer)`
- `String(StringBuilder builder)`

You should use:

```
Integer.toString(foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

In example2, it should be

```
return new String(Integer.toString(foo));
```

Your one doesn't compile. So there's no need to think about the difference between them, they take different parameters.

Comment: new is redundant, you can just `return Integer.toString(foo);`

Answer (score 1):

The first method tries to convert the type to String and creates a new string with that value.
The second method is a constructor which just creates a new string out of a string-like format (not a typeconversion in the sense of Integer -> String).

So the comments are right...it doesnt compile :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any difference between String.valueOf() and new String() apart from the points given by others, as I see both are creating a new String object.
I tried using -

```
    char[] chars = {'c','a','t'};
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(chars) == String.valueOf(chars));
    System.out.println(new String(chars) == new String(chars));
```

Both give **false** stating that both are different String objects.

**So I don't see any performance or memory consumption difference.**

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, the following code pieces produced different results.  Looks like there is some difference when it comes to handling Base64 encoded byte[]

Incorrect:

```
byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) a_imageFile.length()];
FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(a_imageFile);
fis.read(bytesArray);
byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytesArray);            
result = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+ String.valueOf(encoded);
```

Correct:

```
...
result = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+ new String(encoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example of how they differ:

When reading in files and using readAllBytes(), using new String() allows you to print the content of that file.

```
String template = new String(fileName.readAllBytes());
Log.info("File content: " + template;
```

//content of the file is logged like 'hello, this is the content of my txt file'

However, when using String.valueOf, you get the address location instead.

```
String template = String.valueOf(fileName.readAllBytes());
Log.info("File address: " + template;
```

//an address location is logged instead like 'A@24gj49bj'